# Selenium c# to verify the scroll bar position is retained

Tags: selenium, scrollbar, c#-3.0

My requirement is to verify the scroll bar position in a page is retained after manual refresh.

Steps 
-> scroll bar is dragged to bottom of the page or dragged towards particular element
-> triggers manual refresh
-> to verify the scroll bar still remains at bottom of the page (i.e the position of the scroll bar is not changed)

Kindly help me in automating to check the scroll bar position is not changed.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Your code trials? Error trace logs?

Comment: `((IJavaScriptExecutor)_context.WebDriver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_context.WebDriver;
            var value = executor.ExecuteScript("return window.pageYOffset;");
            Console.WriteLine("window offset value:" + value);`

Comment: window.pageYOffset always returns 0
so is there any other way i can get the position of the scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use something similar to get the value of the scroll element.Try this:

```
  public static string JQueryGetValue(this IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element)
    {
        return (string) ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return $(arguments[0]).val();", element);
    }
```

Comment: @HemaLatha check if the right values are passed in the function if this is not working, I suppose you can try to extract the value via Xpath before and after refresh and compare the two. Otherwise this is beyond me and I suggest wait for other ideas.